# SharePoint Online - Share Button is visible for non-owners as well for sub sites

Tags: sharepoint-online, permissions, modern-experience

I have changed the permissions of Share only for Site Owners under Site Permissions -> Site Sharing Permission -> Only site owners can share files, folders and the site. But it is **working only in the root site**, but it is **not working on the sub sites**(it is visible for non-owners as well). Can anyone suggest if there is any solution for this?

Also, does anyone know how to hide the command bar in SharePoint Online for non-owners?
[image]

[image]

[image]

[image]

Comment: Follow the same steps you followed on root site for sub site as well. Can you share screenshot of settings you changed if possible? Are you talking about "Access Request Settings"?

Comment: Thanks for your reply. I have followed the same steps for the subsite, but it is not working. I have added the screenshots for both the queries in the question. Please refer them. Yes, this is regarding the "Access Request Settings".